# Is it possible to increase/decrease the several Delay Time for the same agent after the Delay block was triggered a certain amount?

Tags: anylogic

Hello I want to increase the time of a Delay Block in my Flow Chart after the Delay Block was triggered a certain amount. I have a selectOutput block in front of three delay times to simulate that the Delay times takes different times based on which article is picked. The various delay times blocks are connected to the same agent.

My Process Flow Look like this Process Flow I tried to increase the time manually by using a slider but this only works for capacity and not the time. Is there a possibility to do this automatically?

I also tried adding the function on the delay block.
"if(condition is met) return x;
else return y;"

In order to make this work I also created a Variable called "articlePicked" in the shelves agent.  and added the resource Pool "shelves" to add the code "unit.articlePicked++;" to count how often the variable was count

Unfortunately it did not work. Is it possible to increase the delay time for the same agent?

For a better understanding I added some pictures for clarification.
[image: Delay Function]
[image: Resource Pool Shelve]
[image: Agent Shelve + Variable]

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to create and call functions. In your case:

1. add a func `getDelayTime` that returns a double and takes an arg `numAgentsPassed`
2. in it, you write your logic (if ... else...)
3. Call that from the "Delay time" field of your delay block and pass on the counter value

Comment: Thank You for your help. Sorry that I did not thought about that

Comment: Sorry I am still not able to make it work @Benjamin. I have to use the variable and my function was written correctly?  And what do you mean by counter variable exactly? Should I create a new question with my Problem?

Comment: if you dont knowor dont like creating a function you can also write an expression using ternary operator. It would look like "articlePicked==100? 60: 100". Your code is not working because Anylogic expects to see an expression in Delay Time field, and not statement.